# What are all the things you can bind to in a NSTableColumn of NSPopupButtonCell?

Tags: cocoa, binding, nstablecolumn, nspopupbuttoncell

There are quite a few things you can bind to in a NSTableColumn filled with NSPopupButtonCell, I tried looking around for explanations but couldn't seem to find any.

[image]

- What are each of the binding under value selection for? For example, what's the difference between "Content" and "Content Values"?
- Why is "Content Objects" grayed out anyways?
- Why do you bind to the table column instead of the Pop Up Button Cell? The binding options available for Table Column containing a TextCell is also different. How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help for general explanations of the bindings
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSPopUpButton-DontLinkElementID_801

For help with binding an NSPopupButtonCell and Core Data check out my tutorial at:
http://www.themikeswan.com/blog/?p=81
It will also give you an idea of how the bindings would work for non - Core Data stuff as well.

Comment: Got it. What's the difference between binding the table column vs binding the cell inside though?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact difference is, but I know that for everything I've done with bindings the column has always been the thing to bind to. You could try binding to the cells and see what happens.